# Is it possible to run kubectl within a container within the cluster?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, istio

I have a kubernetes cluster, and I basically have an authenticated api for deploying tasks within the cluster without having kubectl etc set-up locally. I'm aware of the client libraries etc for the Kubernetes api, however they don't seem to support all of the different primatives etc (including some custom ones like Argo). So I just wondered if there was a way I could effectively run `$ kubectl apply -f ./file.yml` within a container on the cluster?

Obviously I can create a container with kubectl installed, but I just wondered how that could then 'connect' to the Kubernetes controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. refer halyard container. spinnaker is deployed from halyard container.

Comment: Great example! I based mine off of that, I didn't realise you had access to the kube api without any real set-up once deployed

Comment: you just need to load kubectl binary inside pod.  Using serviceaccount secret ( token and cert ) kube api can be accessed.

Comment: Please make this answer more complete, otherwise others still don't understand how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can choose from existing ones: https://hub.docker.com/search?q=kubectl&type=image

Answer (score 0):

I found that the roffe/kubectl image works well for running a kubectl apply -f  to deploy to my cluster.  However, you do need to use a ClusterRole and ClusterRoleBinding "attached" to your ServiceAccount, (and the serviceAccount named in your kubectl container), to deploy to any other namespaces.